# Blockchain name using ethers js

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, smartcontracts, ethers.js, etherscan

Is there a way to check name of current blockchain using ethers js
For example

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(rpcUrl);
  
const chainInfo = await providers.getNetwork()
```

gives chain Id and network name but not the blockchain name as etherum or polygon etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `detectNetwork`. You make request to RPC server, so the "name" property depends on the response of the RPC server. For example if you make request binance mainnet

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
  "https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org"
);
const a = provider.detectNetwork().then((x) => console.log(x));
```

you will get this:

```
{
    "name": "bnb",
    "chainId": 56,
    "ensAddress": null,
    "_defaultProvider": null
}
```

But if you make request to "avalance"

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
  "https://api.avax.network/ext/bc/C/rpc"
);
const a = provider.detectNetwork().then((x) => console.log(x));
```

you will get this:

```
{
    "chainId": 43114,
    "name": "unknown"
}
```

It really depends on how the RPC server response is configured. you can find [rpc endpoints here](https://rpc.info/)

Or you can create a mapping for the most popular networks

```
const NETWORKS: { [k: string]: string } = {
  1: "Ethereum Main Network",
  5: "Goerli Test Network",
  42: "Kovan Test Network",
  56: "Binance Smart Chain",
  1337: "Ganache",
};
```

once you get the chainId, you can return

```
NETWORKS[chainId]
```